# Can I edit all but one of the questions out of a disjoint multi-part question?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question, needs-more-focus

I came across [4 program design interview questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143817/4-program-design-interview-questions?rq=1).

Clearly too broad as there are 4 (or 5) completely disjoint parts to it.

But rather than voting to close (which would probably just expire anyway), I thought:

Given that there's already an answer on the photo editor part, I can edit out the remaining parts, leaving us with a useful, reasonably scoped question with an answer.

Is this appropriate to do?

There is an answer on elevator scheduling, but it's fairly low quality (and it should probably be removed regardless, at least in my opinion). But what if there were a decent answers on multiple parts, how should this be handled instead?

Comment: If you can narrow it to one *good* question (Which does not neccessarily mean one question mark), without making any answers (partially) obsolete, that's a clear win in my book. If there are any answers to the parts you want to remove, and they are not atrocious, better leave it be: That would make those answers bad, and editing them would be justly condemned as radical change. The poster would be fully justified to just roll it back, or even (using this same justification) edit it so it matches his answer instead... Anyway, that's a bad multi-question just now.

Comment: @Deduplicator I didn't mean edit the answer, I just meant deleting it after editing of *the question* (but, if the answer has multiple parts, the logical thing would be to editing the now-irrelevant parts out of it, assuming we edit the question).

Comment: Ok, maybe I wasn't clear: If the answer is bad enough, you might be able to justify deleting it, in which case it is no longer relevant. But wanting to edit the question in a way which makes the answer that bad would not meet that bar, instead justifying a rollback with prejudice of the question. Always keep in mind that if you change the question, you assume responsibility for making sure none of the answers are worse for it. I for one would just roll back the change otherwise.